# GSRF sample core project in asp.net with c#

Tags: security, csrf

I want to prevent CSRF in my website. i need sample working project in core asp.net with c#. please share if anybody having or give suggestion how to do that as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

ARMOR is an anti-CSRF library, written in C#, designed to repel CSRF attacks targeting ASP.NET applications. [Here is a tutorial](http://insidethecpu.com/2015/04/10/protecting-asp-net-applications-against-csrf-attacks/) on the subject, and [here is the GitHub repo](https://github.com/daishisystems/Daishi.Armor.WebFramework). Getting up-and-running is simply a matter of

- Applying the necessary configuration settings
- Adding Fortification Filters to the ASP.NET bootstrapper
- Decorating your endpoints with ARMOR attributes
- Dropping the included JavaScript on your UI

**Disclaimer**: I designed and built ARMOR, and the [Encrypted Token Pattern](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Encrypted_Token_Pattern). I’m happy to help you with your implementation.